# How to do multiple plots like Matplotlib (e.g. 2x2) and save into PDF?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I am trying to combine my 4 pages of 4 different graphs into 1 page of graphs organized in a 2x2 fashion. I am using 'Pdfpages' in Python.

In Matplotlib I see that we can do the following to create multiple plots:

```
# Initialise the subplot function using number of rows and columns
figure, axis = plt.subplots(2, 2)
  
# For Sine Function
axis[0, 0].plot(X, Y1)
axis[0, 0].set_title("Sine Function")
  
# For Cosine Function
axis[0, 1].plot(X, Y2)
axis[0, 1].set_title("Cosine Function")
... etc
# Then use pdfpages, e.g. pdf.savefig(figure)
```

However, I have the following using pandas dataframes directly:

```
df1.plot(x='col1', y=['col2', 'col3'], style='-', title=title1)
pdf.savefig()
plt.close()

df2.plot(x='col1', y=['col2', 'col3'], style='-', title=title2)
pdf.savefig()
plt.close()

df3.plot(x='col1', y=['col2', 'col3'], style='-', title=title3)
pdf.savefig()
plt.close()

df4.plot(x='col1', y=['col2', 'col3'], style='-', title=title4)
pdf.savefig()
plt.close()
```

How can I take `df1`...`df4` and make them into a 2x2 plot and then save this onto a single page?

Comment: `fig, axs = plt.subplots(2, 2)`, `df1.plot(..., ax=axs[0, 0])`, `df2.plot(...ax=axs[0, 1])`, and so on.

Comment: Hi thanks @BigBen. Do I just put `ax=axs...` as the last argument to `df.plot` ?

Comment: Yes, as described in the linked thread.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can use:

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=2)
```

And use savefig() and close() after you use .plot() for the four dataframes. Hope this works!
[source](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/visualization.html?highlight=subplots#using-layout-and-targeting-multiple-axes)

Comment: This creates the subplots (as OP already alluded to), but it does not actually plot into each subplot. You need to use the `ax` parameter of `DataFrame.plot`.